# Помогите написать код для автоматизации аккаунта discord

Tags: python, discord, бот

помогите написать автоматизацию аккаунта.

П.с Да я в курсе что дс банит его, но я буду аккуратен, тем более запретный плот всегда сладок.

```py
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")
    
    
    
    @bot.command(aliases = ['пинг'])
    async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send('Понг!')
    
    
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready(): 
        print("Я присоеденился!") # выводит в кмд текст когда бот зайдет на сервер
    
    
      
    
    
    bot.run("ODU0MDgxMzM4Njc2M.Skam_neydalsa.HgF_KeXni7h275GxLOaU") # token
```

Что то типо такого дальше я разберусь.
П.с Да меня забанили в гугле и я не могу загуглить, либо я кретин который даже неспособен загуглить.

Comment: Код, который вы предоставили в кач-ве примера рабочий. Что именно вы хотите автоматизировать непонятно - [добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1318408/edit) пояснений. Но, насколько мне известно, сообщество неохотно помогает в написании кода, который нарушает какие-либо правила

Comment: Не советую распространять токен бота

Comment: Там неправильный токен) просто чтобы понятно было. Но спасибо что беспокоетесь